# KVL equivalent versions

Tags: basic, kirchhoffs-laws

How do the first two statements (quoted below) logically correct when the third is viewed as voltage drops are only across resistors and the voltage rises are only across voltage sources? Where is the equivalence between those three versions?

The book says:

> KLV has three equivalent versions: at any instant around a loop, in either a clockwise or counterclockwise direction,
>
> 1. The algebraic sum of the voltege drops is zero.
> 2. The algebraic sum of the voltege rises is zero.
> 3. The algebraic sum of the voltege drops equals the algebraic sum of the voltege rises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The algebraic sum of the voltage drops is zero.
> 2. The algebraic sum of the voltage rises is zero.

For these to work, you need to be considering each branch voltage as a signed value, measure them all in the same direction around the loop (clockwise or anti-clockwise), and sum all of them together.

If you take just the "voltage drops" that are actually drops, it can't possibly sum to zero. The sum of a bunch of positive numbers can never be zero.

These two versions are equal because if the sum of the drops is \$\sum_n{v_n}\$, then the sum of the rises is \$\sum_n{-v_n}\$ and -0 is equal to 0.

> 1. The algebraic sum of the voltage drops equals the algebraic sum of the voltage rises.

For this to work, you are splitting up branches according to the sign of the branch voltage and considering the "drops" and "rises" separately.

You have

\$\sum_j{v_j} = -\sum_k{v_k}\$,

where all the *v<sub>j</sub>* are positive and all the *v<sub>k</sub>* are negative.

Comment: @ The Photon Thank you very much!!! So, are those first two  like inexact definitions for voltage drop and rise(more like author's way to designate a loop)? When you write the sum of the drops to be positive and rises negative- is that right to view them as sum of the drops to be negative and rises positive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user7777777, I think of the first two as the usual formulation of KVL. The 3rd is equivalent and equally valid, but seems kind of "simplified" to me. It doesn't matter what you consider negative and what you consider positive as long as you use a consistent convention and the net voltage going around the loop comes up to zero.

Comment: @ The Photon  Thank you very much for clarifications, your explanations are helpful!